# Custom Windows Phone MessageBox/Popup

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

I'd like to use a custom MessageBox in my Windows Phone app, similar to the one used when the Bing app identifies a song.  Is there any way to add a custom content component to a MessageBox, or would I need to create my own Popup window that copies the system style?

I know there are libraries (and StackOverflow questions) that allow devs to customize the buttons - I'm looking for a little more customization than that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should use a CustomMessageBox (which is part of the wptoolkit). I have created a messagebox which contains a Listbox from where the  user selects an item in the list. Change the content property to whatever you want to display inside of the messagebox.
Try something like this:

```
ListBox _list = new ListBox();
_list.ItemSource = MySource;
_list.ItemTemplate = MyTemplate;

CustomMessageBox custom = new CustomMessageBox() { Message = "Your message", Content = _list };
custom.Show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/19/windows-phone-7-custom-message-box.aspx).
It basically involves a custom control called **NotificationBox**

Comment: Not really. I found that one earlier, but it appears to only allow custom text on the buttons, which isn't quite what I need.