# wp8 cant find a built-in options menu

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, options-menu

Does anybody know if this control comes with the windows phone 8 SDK or if I must program it?

This screen appears when I go to people => click + icon. There are many very similar screens in windows phone but I don't know if they're ready controls or custom ones.

[image]

What I need is a screen that hides all background and just shows a list of options upon clicking a certain button, and I want to handle application overflow depending on the option the user chose.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CustomMessageBox from toolkit http://phone.codeplex.com

it takes a Content that can be a listbox or user control.
and you can make it take the full screen.

check this: http://shawnoster.com/2012/10/welcome-custommessagebox-to-the-windows-phone-toolkit/

and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15944006/1423885